# Can I/how to specify colors in hex or RGB in nano syntax highlight config?

Tags: vim, colors, nano

I enabled syntax highlight in nano (PHP), but not happy with the default, I would like for example to have the comments displayed in very light grey.

However, the documentation I found seems to suggest I can only write colors like "yellow", "red" etc.

Is there a way to specify a color by its hex/RGB code?
Is there a limitation in the number of colors bash/nano and so on can display? Obviously I am not very experienced with the Linux world.

Same question for VIM, I might switch to VIM if that is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nano is small.  In this case, it limits the choices to the 8 predefined ANSI colors (plus bright/bold) so that it can use the [predefined symbols](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-Colors) from `curses.h` (such as `COLOR_BLUE`) as a guide to naming.

Many terminals support 256 predefined colors; nano can't take advantage of them, but [Vim can](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim).

Terminals which allow directly specifying the R/G/B content of a color are an exception rather than a rule—unlike GUIs.

Some terminals (including Xterm, which I maintain) support the escape sequence `\e]4;N;#RRGGBB\a` to change palette color N to the specified RGB value, and `\e[38;2;R;G;Bm` to set the foreground color to the closest approximation in the palette of the specified RGB value (use `48` instead of `38` for the background color).  **However**, changing a palette color is not useful for nano, because it is taking advantage of the **existing** palette, in contrast with (the much larger) Vim, which can do this with an add-on.

On writing the above in December 2015, the most recent release of nano was version 2.4.2 (July 2015).  At that point, nano was 23336 lines (7657 statements) in C, which was a small fraction of the 131621 lines of text files (counting the ".po" message files).  At the moment (October 2021, six years later), the program size is about the same size (fewer lines, more statements), but the other text files have roughly doubled the size of its source-tree (253036 lines).  It's not exactly "small" any longer (but nowhere near the size of vim).  A couple of weeks before releasing nano 5.0 in July 2020, the developer added eight names for entries in xterm's 256-color palette, in [`src/rcfile.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/rcfile.c#n995):

```
const char hues[COLORCOUNT][8] = { "red", "green", "blue",
                                   "yellow", "cyan", "magenta",
                                   "white", "black", "normal",
                                   "pink", "purple", "mauve",
                                   "lagoon", "mint", "lime",
                                   "peach", "orange", "latte",
                                   "grey", "gray" };

short indices[COLORCOUNT] = { COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE,
                              COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_MAGENTA,
                              COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK, THE_DEFAULT,
                              204, 163, 134, 38, 48, 148, 215, 208, 137,
                              COLOR_BLACK + 8, COLOR_BLACK + 8 };
```

That doesn't appear to be extensible (but at least it uses ncurses).  However, it does not address OP's question because it does not provide a *hex* or *RGB* method for configuring *nano*.  In developing ncurses, I created an example which [reads the X11 rgb.txt file](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/0c4d1c5408cc3ad6e42484ee106c35a0844e9d03/test/picsmap.c#L1738), as part of making the program display X pixmap files in color.  But it also reads and displays using a data file for xterm's [256-color palette](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/xterm-256color.dat).  For screenshots, see the discussion of the [picsmap program](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#compare_picsmap).

Comment: Since GNU Nano version 5.0, on terminals that support at least 256 colors, nine new color names are available (in addition to the 8 predefined ANSI colors): pink, purple, mauve, lagoon, mint, lime,
peach, orange, and latte.

Answer (score 2):

Some six years after this question was asked, a version of nano with this feature was released:

https://9to5linux.com/gnu-nano-6-0-text-editor-is-out-with-new-color-names-suspension-enabled-by-default

Comment: "This release also introduces 14 new color names, including crimson, beet, brick, brown, ocher, plum, rosy, sage, sand, sea, sky, slate, tawny, and teal, **as well as the ability to specify colors as three-digit hexadecimal numbers, in the rgb format**."